# EXTJS 4.2.1 itemSelector - ddReorder does not turn off

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to turn off reordering of items in itemSelector with the following config, per docs:

ddReorder: false

But it still lets me drag and reorder items. Is there anything else I need to turn on/off for this feature to work properly? Or maybe it's just a bug? I'm on version 4.2.1. I apologize in advance if my question is a bit vague, this is my first one. Thanks for any help!

Comment: try with draggable: false. ddReorder and draggable are default to false. If you have set draggable to true then try making to false.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I already tried that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supposed to be a bug in extjs. At the moment the config item ddReorder has no effect on ItemSelector.

ref:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?271699-itemSelector-and-ddReorder&p=996410